# Printing the largest word in given sentence

Tags: c

I'm learning "C" language and here I'm trying to write a program that would print the largest word in string. However, I guess I missed something here or there is a wrong logic in my code. it's not working properly.

```
int main(){
char string[] = "I am at home on Fridays";
    
    int started = 0;
    int longest = 0;

    for (int i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (string[i] == ' ') {
            started = i + 1; //==> prints "riday"
            //if started = i; ==> prints home on Friday
        }
        else {
            if (i - started > longest) {
                started = i - longest;
                longest = started;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("longest word: %.*s\n", started, string + longest);
return 0;
}
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Use a debugger or even a piece of paper to step through your code line by line. That's the best way to understand what the code is doing and why it doesn't work.

Comment: `started = i - longest; longest = started;` shouldn't that just be `longest = i - started;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos for how you are learning C! Your attempt at a *State-Loop* and your proper user of `printf()` using the precision modifier to limit the number of characters output shows you are learning from a good source and have a fairly good handle on what you are doing.

The only thing you really missed was the *State Variable* for your *State Loop*. Huh? What's this *State Loop* and *State Variable* stuff??

When you are iterating and you have multiple, but a limited number of states for your current operation, e.g.

1. in a word reading characters, or
2. before, between or after all words reading spaces.

There are two possible states for the current operation. To keep track of which state you are in inside your *State Loop*, you use a *State Variable*. Here since you only have two-states, a single variable that can indicate `1/0` (e.g. `true/false`) is all you need. so a simple integer like `int inword = 0;` will do fine.

Adding only the `inword` flag to your code, and adding an `int maxlen` to track the length of the longest word are the only variable changes made. The only logic change made was instead of looping until `string[i] = '\0';`, was to loop continually and control exiting the loop from within so if your longest word is the last word, you don't have a special case you have to check after you exit the loop.

Making those changes, I have no doubt you can follow the logic and appreciate how the *State Variable* solves the issues you were having, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    
    char string[] = "  I    am  at home    on    Fridays    ";
    
    int started = 0,        /* index where last word started */
        longest = 0,        /* index where longest word started */
        maxlen = 0,         /* length of the longest word */
        inword = 0;         /* flag inword reading chars 1, between words 0 */

    for (int i = 0;; i++) {                         /* loop continually */
        if (!string[i] || string[i] == ' ') {       /* if end or reading space */
            if (inword) {                           /* if inword */
                int length = i - started;           /* get length of word */
                if (length > maxlen) {              /* check against maxlen */
                    longest = started;              /* update longest start index */
                    maxlen = length;                /* update maxlen */
                }
                inword = 0;                         /* set inword flag false */
            }
            if (!string[i])                         /* if end of string, break */
                break;
        }
        else {  /* reading normal char */
            if (!inword) {                          /* if not inword */
                started = i;                        /* set started to current index */
                inword = 1;                         /* set inword flag true */
            }
        }
    }
    printf ("longest word: %.*s\n", maxlen, string + longest);
}
```

(**note:** how your string to search has been wildly mucked up with additional spaces to show how controlling the state allows you to discard multiple leading, interleaved or trailing whitespace easily)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/str_longest_state
longest word: Fridays
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation This is pretty clear now. I can see where things were missed up. But one question though, "inword" variable meant if it's really reading words then it's 1 or true and if it's between words (meaning reading space for example) is 0?

Comment: Yep, you got it 100%. It's a simple `1/0` or `true/false` flag. It is set true when you are in-a-word or false otherwise. Good job! A *State Loop* is a great way to parse just about anything you need. You can handle incredibly complex parsing (like reading a Periodic table, etc..) by adding just a few more conditions (*State Variables*)

Answer (score 1):

I think the logic would need to be revised. It has to track/store the longest word found so far during iterating the array (either based on start and end index or the word itself). You can use the space character as an indicator of moving to the next word as well as count the word length.

Sample output for below code:

```
Current word startIdx: 0, endIdx: 0, Len: 1
Current word startIdx: 2, endIdx: 3, Len: 2
Current word startIdx: 5, endIdx: 6, Len: 2
Current word startIdx: 8, endIdx: 11, Len: 4
Current word startIdx: 13, endIdx: 14, Len: 2
Current word startIdx: 16, endIdx: 22, Len: 7
Longest string: Fridays
```

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char string[] = "I am at home on Fridays";

    //Try with other input
    //char string[] = "Fridays on home at am I";

    //We basically need to track (1) the start index and (2) end index of the word
    //and also (3) the longest length so far.
    //All of the above can be done in one pass.
    int startIdx=0, endIdx=0, longestLen = 0;
    int longestStartIdx, longestEndIdx;

    int strLen = strlen(string);
    for (int i = 0; i <= strLen; i++) {
        if ((string[i] == ' ') || (i == strLen)) { //meaning it moves to the next word or already at the end of the string
            endIdx = i - 1;
            //calculate the len of the word and update the longest if > current longest
            int wordLen = endIdx - startIdx + 1;
            printf("Current word startIdx: %d, endIdx: %d, Len: %d\n", startIdx, endIdx, wordLen);
            if (wordLen > longestLen) {
                longestLen = wordLen;
                longestStartIdx = startIdx; longestEndIdx = endIdx;
            } //end if

            //reset the startIdx
            startIdx = i+1;
        }
    } //end for

    char longestString[longestLen+1];
    strncpy(longestString, string + longestStartIdx, longestLen);
    printf("Longest string: %s\n", longestString);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's actually nice. I suspect you meant to `#include <string.h>` instead of `stdlib.h`. You can remove `longestEndIdx` as a variable, it isn't used and you should initialize `int longestStartIdx = 0;` to avoid the `"may be used uninitialized"` warning. You may also want to add an `if (wordLen)` before your `printf()` to handle `char string[] = "  I   am   at    home  on   Fridays   ";` a bit more gracefully. Works just fine.